# Заполнение полей таблицы в обозревателе серверов не числами, а константами? (EF, CodeFirst)

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

У меня есть модель, представляющая в БД книги.

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Publishing Publishing { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
    public int? PageCount { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public int SellCount { get; set; }
}
```

Language это перечисление со списками языков. Но вот когда я пытаюсь заполнить сам таблицу новыми книгами, то мне приходится использовать не именованные константы, которые я определил, а их числовые значения. Сразу же появилась мысль, что я делаю что-то не так.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Возможно ли заполнять перечисления в своей таблице в виде выпадающего списка, а не чисел?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам по себе Enum это число. Так что в этом нет ничего удивительного, что в БД оно представлено в виде числа. Но если вам всё таки нужно представить его в виде строки, то попробуйте такой вариант: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721246/ef-core-2-0-enums-stored-as-string

Comment: К сожалению, ваш ответ больше подойдёт к комментарию, но так как вы не достигли достаточной репутации вы можете дополнить ответ информацией с помощью кнопки [edit]